# how to move checkbox text to left programmatically

Tags: android

I want to move my checkbox to the right of its text programmatically and I tried some way but they didn't work.

it's my code:

```
public class CheckBoxRegularFa extends AppCompatCheckBox {
 public CheckBoxRegularFa(Context context) {

    super(context);
    init();
}

public CheckBoxRegularFa(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public CheckBoxRegularFa(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {

    setTypeface(AppController.getInstance().getFont(FontType.Medium));
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21)
    {

        ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{

                        new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled},
                        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled}
                },
                new int[] {

                        Color.BLACK
                        ,getResources().getColor(R.color.color_primary)
                }
        );
        setButtonTintList(colorStateList);
    }
}
}
```

there is some solution in XML but I want to do this programmatically.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move the checkbox to the right of its text programmatically you have to set the **Layout Direction** to be **Right-to-Left** like below:

```
checkBoxRegularFa.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

**Output for Right to Left:**

[image: rtl]

And if you want to change it back to its initial state **Left-to-Right** will be like below:

```
checkBoxRegularFa.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
```

**Output for Left to Right:**

[image: ltr]